# Laravel Passport Key path oauth-public.key does not exist or is not readable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Laravel passport showing this while trying to access resource

```
Key path "file://C:\xampp\htdocs\rental_5.0\storage\oauth-public.key" does not exist or is not readable
```

Comment: Well, what are the permissions? Also, where is the location of your `openssl` executable

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You do not mention your installation steps. Presume you did the following:

```sh
composer require laravel/passport
```

Register the service provider inside `config/app.php`

```php
Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
```

Run the migrations

```sh
php artisan migrate
```

Lastly generate the keys using

```sh
php artisan passport:install
```

I see you are trying it on Windows. I saw an [OpenSSL problem on Windows](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/48), might help you.

Comment: Up for OpenSSL problem on windowns, GnuWin seems to be my issue

Comment: anyone facing this issue in production laravel forge, you need to simply ssh into forge "ssh forge@ip_address_here" , then just run "php artisan passport:install --force" (force to overwrite the keys)
This will generate the keys and have them in place

Answer (score 56):

This is because you didn't generate Oauth  keys using passport keys.

Run

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

After that run the following command to generate a personal access client

```
php artisan passport:client --personal
```

Enter the details it asks you. Then you are done.

Answer (score 7):

May be `storage/oauth-private.key` and `storage/oauth-private.key` are absent and you imported the old database. For this scenario please run the following command.

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

> Try this solution if you imported the old database where passport related data already stored. Otherwise, follow the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same error with Ubuntu and in my case the problem was with permissions, running this solved the issue:

`sudo chown www-data:www-data storage/oauth-*.key`

Answer (score 5):

We get this error because `passport` is not installed correctly

Solution is simple just run this command:

```
php artisan passport:install
```

Answer (score 4):

go straight to .gitignore file in the root of laravel project and remove **/storage/*.key** line. Perhaps your server isn't allowing to write the keys file in the directory. Upload or publish your repo again.

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSL was not installed on my windows machine

1. Download **GnuWi**
2. Extract `bin/openssl.exe` into a Environment Variable Path directory (You can create your own bin folder in your user folder or something and add that path to the Path Variable)
3. Open a new command prompt(Existing ones may not have the newest environment variables)
4. Run `php artisan passport:install`

https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/48#issuecomment-241936338

### Edited

In windows by using `git BASH` you don't need to install any additional software only run `php artisan passport:install` from `BASH` and it should work.

Comment: I opened git bash from project folder. then run php artisan passport:install
then run php artisan serve from git bash. Next i give a request from postman and it works thanks for this edition

Answer (score 2):

I use Heroku. As far as I know, Heroku add OpenSSL support by default (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support).

All the things, like `php artisan install:passport` did run without any issue and my project is also available on the web.

When I asked for `php artisan route:list` then I received this exception:

```
[LogicException]
  Key path "file:///app/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable
```

What seems to me the same as above.

I did everything also local successfully. After these steps git showed I have the key filed in my storage folder, so I committed and pushed them to Heroku.

This solved the issue, now everything is okay also on Heroku.

(Is it okay, to have the same keys here and there?)

Comment: If you are in windows, you should install openSSL(please read the post below) and I am not sure if is it ok or not but for security reasons please add another key in production.

Comment: I think your answer deserves a vote up. For what ever reason , may be for safety purpose, it was ignored in the .gitignore and heroku is throwing error 500. So in my case i just have to remove it from .gitignore and pushed and it is working. I also tried running php artisan passport:install or passport:keys on heroku using the command line but it did not work.

Comment: It's generally a bad practice to have private keys in version control.

Comment: I found a solution running with heroku cli

`heroku ps:exec` then running  command `php artisan passport:keys`

Answer (score 0):

I manually set my `password_client` value in the `oauth_clients` table to `1` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked fine on the local system, faced the same problem on production system. In my case, git ignored keys for good reason.
Just executed `php artisan passport:keys` on production server everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case It just doesnt work - I try everyging - probably problem with file access (however `ls -la` looks fine) - so i generate that keys in other machine and copy to serwer - and `php artisan passport:install` start works

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to composer.json did the trick for me:

```
"scripts": { "post-install-cmd": [ "php artisan clear-compiled", "php artisan optimize", "chmod -R 777 storage", "php artisan passport:keys" ], }
```

https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/267#issuecomment-346627625

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the ideal solution but removing `/storage/*.key` from `.gitignore` then pushing did the trick for me.

Comment: yes, but the issue is the permissions we have to set permissions though.

Comment: No, that's not ideal solution. You should generate a new `*.key` file on your server. Don't copy it from your local machine. Otherwise, your bearer token key from server will be able to crack  with `*.key` from your local machine.

Comment: I agree with you @fendiSetiawan.

Comment: I agree with that too. It was a quick solution at the time